# Method not found ExecuteQueryAsync when ApplyingProvisioningTemplate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

So I followed the tutorial here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine but I am encountering this issue

Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQueryAsync()'

Here is my code

```
private static void ApplyProvisioningTemplate(string targetWebUrl, string userName, SecureString pwd)
{
    using (var context = new ClientContext(targetWebUrl))
    {
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, pwd);
        Web web = context.Web;
        context.Load(web, w => w.Title);
        context.ExecuteQueryRetry();

        // Configure the XML file system provider
        XMLTemplateProvider provider = new XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider(String.Format(@"C:\temp\pnpprovisioningdemo"),"");

        // Load the template from the XML stored copy
        ProvisioningTemplate template = provider.GetTemplate("PnPProvisioningDemo.xml");

        // We can also use Apply-SPOProvisioningTemplate
        web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(template);

    }
}
```

Error happens in `context.ExecuteQueryRetry();`
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is ExecuteQueryAsync() in the ClientContext class:

[ClientContext class screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGl87.png)

Maybe the method is wrong,replace the context with the code below `context.ExecuteQueryRetry ()`:

```
context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was able to see that ExecuteQueryAsync is not in my ClientContext class, turns out I am using an old version of Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll, now I updated it to latest version, but now I encounter this error '"Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Marketplace.CorporateCuratedGallery.SiteCollectionCorporateCatalogAccessor' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'."'  I don't understand why it could not load it, I can clearly see from the Object Browser that it is there.

Comment: We could try to run “Install-SPApplicationContent“,If that doesn't work, we could create an empty project, add the latest reference, and move existing code over, possibly with other reference associations causing errors.